# TLS error when pip installing with virtual env

Tags: python, opencv, virtualenv

I'm trying to install opencv using

```
pip install opencv-python
```

in the virtual env I have tensor flow installed in and I get the error

```
 Collecting opencv-python
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:661) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

It installs when I use a diff env, but it only installs 3.4.0.12 and I want 3.4.1

Comment: There is no 3.4.1 yet at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#history) now, the latest version is 3.4.0.12. If you need development version you probably want to install from Git.

Comment: Is there a guide on how to install from git because I couldn't find one

Comment: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#build-process